# Is there a name for adjectives that are based around someone's name?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, adjectives, names

Some examples would include:

- Shakespearean
- Christian
- Mesmerized
- Pavlovian
- Newtonian
- Boolean
- Darwinian

Comment: Nymonym? Nomonym?

Comment: *Christ* is not a name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are *[eponymous adjectives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English)*.  Wikipedia says:

> An **eponymous adjective** is an adjective which has been derived from the name of a person, real or fictional. Persons from whose name the adjectives have been derived are called [eponyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym).

It follows with a more-or-less comprehensive list that might be worth looking at.