# Changing a person's name into an adjective

Tags: nouns, adjectives

What do you call it when a person's name or group's name is changed into a adjective? Is it "conversion" or "functional shift"?

For instance, saying a band's music is "Beatlesque" or that someone's singing will be "Aguilerian" (implying she will be singing with some gusto).

Comment: There's interesting analysis in the 'What are the limits of using the suffix “-esque”?' thread. What you describe is known as _agglutination_ or _derivation_ (the process of forming new words from existing ones by adding affixes to them, like _shame_ + _less_ + _ness_ → _shamelessness_). _Conversion_ (linguistics) (also known as _zero affixation_) means forming a new word from an existing identical one, like forming the verb _green_ from the existing adjective. [ [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_formation)]

Comment: Since [derivational morphology](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) is notoriously irregular, pretty much any of the adjective-forming suffixes can be attached with impunity to a proper name: _That was a Davish thing to do_. Similarly, _Georgian, Kately, Thomistic, Hanky,_ etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's called an ***eponymous adjective.***

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_eponymous_adjectives_in_English):

> An **eponymous adjective** is an adjective which has been derived from the name of a person, real or fictional. Persons from whose name the adjectives have been derived are called **eponyms**.

The linked article has a huge list of such words.

Comment: The question seems to ask for the name of the process, not the result. There are already two questions about what to call adjectives like this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45577/is-there-a-name-for-adjectives-that-are-based-around-someones-name 
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196636/when-a-phenomenon-usually-a-proper-name-becomes-an-adjective?rq=1

Comment: @sumelic - Obviously, it's *eponymous adjectification*.  (And is there any reason why you did not mark this question as a dupe of the other two?)